# Calling Jinja block from included file

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-admin

I am building a little web application in Python 3.5, using Flask 0.11.1 and Flask-Admin 1.4.2.

Instead of using Flask-Admin as an administrative interface (only used by administrators of the website), I want it to be used by all the users of the website (to take profit of its awesome CRUD generation with forms using Select2 JS lib, inline forms, list views with filtering, etc.).

With that in mind, I want to override the list view template to be more user-friendly. For that, I am doing the following.

First, in my view I override `list_template`:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class FriendView(ModelView):

    list_template = 'friend/list.html'
    ...
```

Then, I write the `friend/list.html` file by extending `admin/model/list.html` and overriding the block `model_list_table` defined in it:

```
{% extends 'admin/model/list.html' %}

{% block model_list_table %}
  {% for row in data %}
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      {% include 'friend/panel.html' %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The `panel.html` file represents a Bootstrap `panel` illustrating each Friend:

```
<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    This friend is named {{ row.name }}.
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    {% block list_row_actions_column scoped %}
      {{ super() }}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the problem: as you can see, I use in `panel.html` the block `list_row_actions_column`, which is a Jinja block defined in `admin/model/list.html`.
Of course, this raises the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: there is no parent block called 'list_row_actions_column'.
```

because the file `panel.html` is not extending `admin/model/list.html`.

I have tried to define `panel` as a Jinja `macro` and to import it in `friend/list.html`, this raises the same error...

I know that I could simply not separate the panel in another file, however my `friend/list.html` is pretty big, and I think it is a good thing to do it that way, for sake of readibility and decoupling.

Does someone have an idea about how I can proceed?

Thanks,
Edouard

Comment: I don't think this is going to work this way. You need to do it the other way around and let `panel.html`extend your `list.html` which extends `admin/model/list.html`. This way you will get access to `list_row_actions_column`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. However, I want to put more than one `panel` in my `list.html`. If my `panel.html` extends my `list.html`, I need to return the `panel.html` as a template, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

just make an html file and write single block of code in html file then include that file into that particular location where you want to need that code. that is the best method without use of any #block or #micro and for every block of code use a new html file and use this file as a function by including it on that place.

Comment: This does not answer OPs question in specific. Please add code to illustrate your point